# Vue components are not recognized by vscode autocomplete with typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, components

I'm using vue 3 with typescript, but my components are not being recognized by the typescript auto complete in vscode.
The page are rendered correctly, only in the vscode is not recognizing my components.

My code to dynamically import components is as shown below:

```js
import AppView from '@src/vue/App.vue'
const app = createApp(AppView)

const components = import.meta.glob('@client/modules/*/components/**/*.vue'),
for (const module in components) {
    const moduleComponents = components[module]
    /**Register Components */
    moduleComponents.forEach((component: any) => {
        const name = `${module}-${component.name}`
        app.component(name, defineAsyncComponent(component.import))
    })
}
```

I have a component like this

```
<template>
    <div :class="'row justify-'+align">
        <slot></slot>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
type Aligns = 'start' | 'center' | 'end' | 'around' | 'between' | 'evenly';

defineProps<{
    align: {
        type: Aligns,
        default: 'start'
    }
}>()
</script>
```

I already have the recomended extensions for vue and typescript in my vscode. The library components are recognized as intend, only my components imported in `import.meta.glob` are not working.

If this way of import dont work with typescript, is there a way to import the components manually that the typescript recognize? Like putting something in some `.d.ts` file or anything else.